# Django DecimalField not respecting max_digits and causing Buffer Overflow/Truncation

Tags: sql-server, django, pyodbc

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server with Django 2.0.1

This is actually happening among all my decimal fields and I'm hoping I'm missing something simple.

I have declared in my models:

```
Overhead = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=4, db_column='overhead')
```

A modelform is made with it, and it actually validates having too many digits (ex: 100.0000), and updates correctly when set to one less than the declared amount (ex: 9.0000).  Any amount of digits matching max_digits gives a truncation error:

```
String data, right truncation: length 14 buffer 12
```

If I repeat the same situation with a DecimalField declared like:

```
models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, db_column='subtotal')
```

I get the same error type from the database driver (22001) and a slightly different amount of overflow:

```
String data, right truncation: length 26 buffer 24
```

The SQL that gets generated for the update statement in the log can be copy/pasted and with the exact same parameters in the SQL Editor for SQL Server, and it updates the records happily. I keep thinking something is happening in-between when Django compiles the SQL and the Database driver executing it, but I'm not sure what I would even be looking for, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/367).

Comment: 100% right on the duplicate, upgrading to 4.0.23 for pyodbc solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to 4.0.23 for pyodbc solved the issue as per Gord Thompson's comment.